# Using a function with ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When using the `ForEach-Object` function, is there a way to provide a `function` instead of a `code block`.

This would enable me to simplify this:

```
@(1, 2, 3, 4) | % { Add-One $_ }
```

to this, or similar:

```
@(1, 2, 3, 4) | % Add-One
```

For completeness here is the current definition of the `Add-One` function

```
function Add-One($Number) {
    return $Number + 1
}
```

It's easy to write a function with `process` to do something similar, like so:

```
@(1, 2, 3, 4) | Add-One
```

However, this means that you have to re-implement the loop and `ValueFromPipeline` for each function instead of reusing what `ForEach-Object` already provides. So in short is there a way to use a scalar function with `ForEach-Object` that avoids wrapping it in a `Code Block`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can use a scriptblock like so:

```
PS> $sb = { process { $_ + 1 }}
PS> 1..4 | % $sb
2
3
4
5
```

But perhaps a more straightforward approach is to create a filter:

```
filter Add-One { $_ + 1 }
1..4 | Add-One
```

You can also use a function e.g.:

```
function Add-One {process {$_ + 1}}
1..4 | Add-One
```

Filter is basically a function with an implied process block.  The advanced function approach looks like this:

```
function Add-One {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [int[]]
        $Number
    )
    process {
        foreach ($n in $Number) {$n + 1}
    }
 }
1..4 | Add-One
Add-One (1..4)
```

Comment: For those like me who are searching for the `filter` documentation, it's in `about_Functions`:   
"A filter is a type of function that runs on each object in the pipeline. A filter resembles a function with all its statements in a Process block. The syntax of a filter is as follows:  
          `filter [<scope:>]<name> {<statement list>}`"